# Home Network Using Tethered Mobile Phone as Internet Connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

Currently I live in a very remote area so ADSL/Cable etc is not an option. Luckily I am able to get decent mobile phone coverage and my contract includes unlimited tethering support.

I would like to connect all devices in the house to connect to a single wireless device & that device in turn to use the mobile phone as the internet connection. Are there routers that are capable of this or would it be wise to use a PC or Raspberry Pi type device?

If I were to go the PC route I assume I would need to start dealing with DHCP software, 2 wireless cards?

Any advice or pointers on a solution that could fit the bill would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just use the wireless hotspot feature of the phone? Or does it not support this? For around the price of the devices you are talking about buying you could buy a cheap Android smartphone with a Wi-Fi hotspot function built in.

Comment: Hi, I'd like to have the advantages of a home network, file server, shared folders, printers etc.

Comment: If your phone doesn't force client isolation then some of these features should still work when connected to the hotspot.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is an "LTE router". This device, which will generally resemble a WiFi access point, will perform the tethering (it has a SIM card slot), and expose WiFi and Ethernet connectivity in the same way as a DSL router.

An alternative option would be to simply use an always-on mobile phone with a (non-routing) WiFi access point... but the extra WiFi traffic would tend to slow things down, and I would expect lower overall reliability.